# Sony Ericsson phone not recognized on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, mobile-phone, nokia-pc-suite

I am trying to use "PC Suite for Sony Ericsson" or "[My Phone Explorer](http://myphoneexplorer.software.informer.com/)" to synchronize the content (SMS, Contacts, etc) of my phone (K810) with PC. But none of those softwares recognize my phone when it is connected to PC through a USB cable. I thought maybe the required USB drivers for Sony Ericsson were missing, so I downloaded [this](http://www.sonymobile.com/us/tools/sony-ericsson-drivers/), but when I run it, even the installer does not detect the connected phone and installing the drivers fails as well. What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried on another PC? How about with another cable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

[PC Software for K810 (from sonymobile.com)](http://www.sonymobile.com/us/software/phones/k810/)

If you still can't access your files via software try opening it in Windows Explorer (if it's recognized it'll be in My Computer).

Alternatively boot a different operating system live CD and try opening it from it. I've got an old MP3 I couldn't open on Windows (wasn't recognized) and could open it on Fedora (just open to get the files, there wasn't any software available, though). Or just try on a different computer...

Edit: I remember I also had an old webcam with no drivers for Windows 7, just XP, so I installed it on a virtual machine and it worked - since it's an old cellphone you could try that if nothing works...

Comment: After installing the "PC Software for K810", I could get "My Phone Explorer" to work. Thank you.